# Images are messed up in webkit

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit, image-rotation

[image]On this page http://cacrochester.com/ the 2 rotating images are messed up in webkit browsers. It's not all the time, and it's usually not on the first image. Why is that?

I'm using the NivoSlider jquery plugin to rotate the images.

here's what i'm seeing.

Comment: It looks crap for me in Firefox too

Comment: It looks like it's working fine on FF 3.6.3 for me. What version are you on?

Comment: Can you be more specific with what about them is "messed up?"  Please describe the behavior you expect to see vs. what you're actually seeing.

Comment: The first image looks fine, but when the second image is rotated in, it's all chopped and repeated all the way to the right edge of the container overlapping the events box.

Comment: btw. try some antialiasing on the font ;-)

Comment: Looks fine to me in Safari (5.0.2) and Chrome (6.0.472.63) on OS X 10.6. Reloaded a number of times, but it's all good.

Comment: It looks the same to me in both Firefox and Safari. Are you sure you're not just trying to convert some programmers?

Comment: Can you guys see the screenshot i uploaded? i'm at work and i can't tell if it uploaded correctly or not.

Comment: The solution I posted works on my local machine. Give it a shot.

Comment: I think it looks perfect for the sentence and context it is in :) +1

Comment: How were images created? Photoshop? Were they created for the web? What resolution are you using? Idon't have the issue, but the images are really pixelated. I'm using Firefox 3.5.13

Comment: It might be an issue with your internet connection.  The image file might be still downloading as it is getting displayed.  What are your operating system specs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing this strange effect you say, the issue seems to be in the way each column is shown. Nevertheles, you should try any other solution for that page you're building, since the effect you're applying fits more to a turning marquee and not to a slider... I've seen lots of real cool sliders (look jquery slider on Google or see http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/ ).

Aside, you have to consider remaking the imgs, the text is really ugly (I hope you don't be angry at me saying this, since I'm trying to help your page look better). As I was saying, if you use a Photo editing soft like Photoshop you should set the text anti-aliasing to sharp or crisp but not to "none" (therefore you won't see it "pixelated" anymore). And de photo of the guy is kinda pixelated too...

Hope my 2 cents can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `<div id="slider">` element

```
style="float:right;position: relative;height:270px;width:610px;"
```

Comment: I already have those styles on #slider except position relative. Position: relative is added dynamically though through the nivoSlider plugin so even when i add it in chrome's developer tools (basically like firebug), it just crosses it out.

Comment: I know you did but I imagine the way the script is written these values are not getting pulled correctly via the stylsheet. Adding it to the div directly seems to correct the issue. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

nivo-slider.css, lines 36, 37:

```
.nivo-slice {
     display: none;
     /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks totally fine to me.  Maybe try a different Jquery scroll plugin.